# How to allow a currency (and general numeric) column in the dataset to be added into the `values` section in `Analyze in Excel`?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In the dataset (import mode) I have got multiple general (numeric) and currency columns. In the column `summarization` property I have selected `Sum` as shown below.

[image]

When I open this dataset via `Analyze in excel` then I cannot use this column in the `values` section. I can only add it under the `rows` section.

How to allow a currency (and general numeric) column in the dataset to be added into the `values` section in `Analyze in Excel`?

Error:

[image]

Comment: You must create a measure based on this column;

Comment: So only measures can be added under the excel pivot's `values` section?